# Find List item that populated clicked Table-layout row:

Tags: android, list, onclick, android-tablelayout

I have an activity that contains a TableLayout. I'm populating this table programmaticly by data i have in a list:

what i need to do is to make every row clickable and when it's click I need to find the corresponding item in the list so i can get extra data out of it, this is my `onCreate` code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reports_list_activity_layout);
    application = (SGRaportManagerAppObj)getApplication();
    reportsRepository = application.reportsRepository.getReportsRepository();
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableReportsList);
    table.setStretchAllColumns(true);  
    table.setShrinkAllColumns(true);  

    for (Report tempReport : reportsRepository)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setClickable(true);
        TextView tvName = new TextView(this);
        tvName.setText(tempReport.getName());
        tvName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        tvName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_black));  
        row.addView(tvName);
        TextView tvPath = new TextView(this);
        tvPath.setText(tempReport.getPath());
        tvPath.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        tvPath.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_black));
        row.addView(tvPath);
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(Report.JSON_KEY_ID, );
            }
        });
        table.addView(row);   
    }
}
```

so what I need here is when the row is clicked i need to find it in the list and get the ID of the report that was clicked in the table and put into the Map object to pass foreword.
does anyone know how is this can be done?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hashtable that maps the content you show in the table row (say Report ID) againsg the Report Object

So something like

```
Hashtable map = new Hashtable();
...
map.put(report.getId(), report);
```

onClick on table row, manage to get the report id and in turn look it up this hashtable you are maintaining at a class level or somewhere accessible ..

Edit(code block)

```
class MyTableRow extends TableRow{

    Object report = null;
    public MyTableRow(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Object getReport() {
        return report;
    }

    public void setReport(Object report) {
        this.report = report;
    }   
}
```

in the onCreate() of your activity, jus use MyTableRow class instead of TableRow like 
tableRow = new MyTableRow(this) and use tableRow.setMethod(reportObject) to set the Report. should work..

Comment: yes i thought of some thing like that, but i think, is there a way to perform this operation without a third-party object.

Comment: in fact,  we can @EmilAdz, we jus need to come up with MyTableRow class extending TableRow class and then add an object of type Report and a method to get and set it at will..

Comment: this looks like the solution I'm looking for, I will try that and accept your answer if this works. do you maybe have an example that does some thing like this?

Comment: yes, i jus tried tweaking with my existing code here, runs smooth and as per requirement. pLease check my edit on this post. let us know if you run into any issue

Comment: you answer is accepted, actually for now I'm using your first suggestion i will try the modified class, later. Thank you very much for you help.